# Warning coming from a pod depending on another one

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode8

I am using [CoreBitcoin](https://github.com/oleganza/CoreBitcoin) with Pod. It comes with two other pods, one is [OpenSSL-Universal](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL) v(1.0.1.16). according to OpenSSL-Universal Github, many people was facing some warning like

```
`ld: warning: object file (/Users/me/projet/myProject/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a(cversion.o)) was built for newer iOS version (9.2) than being linked (8.0)
`
```

as mentionned [here](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL/issues/21)

I already tried disabling all warning from pod project, it does disable all warning from the pod I did install, but not from the ones coming as dependencies of some pod.

I tried to install newer OpenSSL-Universal pod myself, but as you can imagine, it didn't solved my problem. It's just a warning problem so what I'm looking for  :

- Can I find a way with my podfile to install CoreBitcoin with a newer version of OpenSSL-Universal, so new people working on the project would just have to clone it and won't have tons of warnings

or

- What kind of settings could I set to disable those warnings once for all

I am using Xcode v8.3.3 & pod v1.2.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843900/xcode-7-warnings-object-file-was-built-for-newer-ios-version-than-being-linked or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270491/xcode-7-warning-was-built-for-newer-ios-version-5-1-1-than-being-linked-5-1

Comment: Thanks @Oleshko but in my case, I can't upgrade my target deployment, since everything is working fine and some of our customer use old iOS version. this is just due to the link between OpenSSL-Universal and CoreBitcoin and an issue for this specific version of OpenSSL-Universal as I mentioned. Note that this issue is fixed for >1.0.1.16 version of OpenSSL-Universal

Comment: To fix all the warning I decided to fork the project on my own Github, update the podspec on my own, now warning are done. thanks

Comment: Then have you tried go to targets/Build Settings/Linking/Other Linker Flags and add -w?

Comment: I did, it removed all the warning from pods, which could have been kinda dangerous in my opinion, since I just wanted only a specific pod to stop warning. however, thanks for the tips, it might be usefull sometime :)

Answer (score 0):

Give, please, more info about Pods. My solution is:

```
target 'YOURAPPLICATIONNAME' do
    pod 'CoreBitcoin'
    end
```

And others dependencies I install with add `pod 'NameOfPod'`

For use in Swift-project, you must be create bridging header and import CoreBitcoin to file, than you can use any methods from library.